# С++,Ошибка: undeclared identifier

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте мне необходимо сделать проект по учебе, и я столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Есть абстрактный класс Entity, от него наследуются классы Product, Client, Sale
Так же есть абстрактный класс ListData, который отвечает хранение и управление списком list, о него так же наследуются  ProductsData, ClientsData, SalesData. И возникает совершенно не понятная мне ошибка 'Sale': undeclared identifier:

```
#include "ListData.h"
#include "Sale.h"
class SalesData : public ListData
{
public:
    void Add(shared_ptr<Entity> item) override {
        if (item == NULL)
            return;
        if (item->GetID() == 0)
            item->SetID(NextID());
        ListData::Add(item);
        Sale* sale = NULL; //Здесь ошибка
    }
};
```

Ошибка возникает на этапе компиляции проекта, причем следующий код без ошибки:

```
#include "ListData.h"
#include "Product.h"
class ProductsData : public ListData
{
public:
    void Add(shared_ptr<Entity> item) override {
        if (item == NULL)
            return;
        if (item->GetID() == 0)
            item->SetID(NextID());
        ListData::Add(item);
        Product* product = NULL;
    }
};
```

Код "Sale.h":

```
#include "Entity.h"
#include "System.h"
class Sale :
    public Entity
{
private:
    int product_id;
    int client_id;
    Date date_sale;
    Date date_delivery;
    int pcount;
    int summary_pay;
public:
    Sale();
    Sale(int _product_id, int _client_id, Date _date_sale, Date _date_delivery, int _count);
    Sale(int id, int _product_id, int _client_id, Date _date_sale, Date _date_delivery, int _count);
    int GetProductID();
    int GetClientID();
    Date GetDateSale();
    Date GetDateDelivery();
    int GetCount();
    int GetSummatyPay();
    void SetSummaryPay(int pay);
    string ToString() override;
};
```

Помогите пожалуйста, плюс приемлю любую критику по проекту.
Полностью код можно посмотреть на:
https://github.com/nikitavasilev03/OnlineShop-Project-SAOD-

Comment: А что в `Sale.h`? Там есть класс/структура `Sale`?

Comment: Скрины плохая идея для вопроса, логов ошибки нету

Comment: У вас точно в `Sale.h` объявлен класс `Sale`? И еще - не надо тут приводить копии экрана; приводите текст.

Comment: Кстати, а какой вообще глубокий смысл в этой строчке? В переменной `sale`, которат тут же будет уничтожена - на выходе из функции?

Comment: Я исправил. Смысла именно в этой строчке нет, но мне необходимо использовать указатель на класс Sale в дальнейшем здесь же

Comment: Не воспроизводится... Компилирую ваш OnlineShop.cpp, который включает System.h, который включает SalesData.h - все нормально...

Comment: ну все и должно быть нормально, тока я не могу понять почему у меня не нормально